# Systems Loader/ Boot systems

Tags: boot, boot-loader

I have installed WIN 7 on my laptop, and currently I need to install other systems for test my app, Where can I find good boot  loader for add/remove/ load a few systems ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not add the other systems as virtual machines running on top of your windows installation? This seems like an ideal use for VMWare, and even probably better than using the multi-boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRUB (Grand Unified Boot Loader) can boot most any operating system. Easiest way to get it -- install Ubuntu alongside your Windows installation. That will give you a new bootloader, one more OS, and a good example of how to add further operating systems.

Comment: Can I load mac os from grub ?